# Is possible to customize passport scope message in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I'm creating an API with an authentication system using passport. I'm also using token scopes, for user permissions and everything is working fine.

My problem is, when a route e reached by an user without permission to access that route a 403
INVALID SCOPE(S) PROVIDED error page is returned. I would like to send some JSON message instead this error, but is not working.

My code:

File api.php

```
Route::post('/products/create', [BooksController::class, 'create'])->middleware(['auth:api', 
'scope:create']);
Route::put('/products/update/{id}', [BooksController::class, 'update'])- 
>middleware(['auth:api', 'scope:edit']);
Route::delete('/products/delete/{id}', [BooksController::class, 'destroy'])- 
>middleware(['auth:api', 'scope:delete']);
```

File BooksController.php

```
 public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->user()->tokenCan('delete')) {

        return response()->json(['success' => "Destroy reached"], 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => "You cannot reach this route"], 400);
    }

}
```

File AuthServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Passport::tokensCan([
        'edit' => 'can edit books',
        'create' => 'can add books',
        'delete' => 'can delete books',
    ]);
    Passport::routes();
}
```

Comment: Since you're manually checking your scope inside of your route, just remove your `scope:delete` middleware.

Comment: Yes that work. And what if I wouldn't check inside the route, how I could customize the message?

Comment: There's no built in way to customize the message. You could write your own middleware to provide the response you want, and use that instead of the built in middleware. Or, you could customize your application exception handler to provide a custom response for the `\Laravel\Passport\Exceptions\MissingScopeException` exception, which is what is thrown by the passport middleware and provides that message.